# Create a popup with radio buttons

Tags: c#-4.0, messagebox

I have a program that downloads and installs two filetypes, '.zip' and '.craft'. If the file is a .zip, the process is fairly easy, but if it is a .craft, there are two locations that the file can be placed into that i cannot programatically decide upon without user interaction.

Is there a way to make a message box that offers a pair of radio buttons that the user can then use to choose where to place this .craft file?

Kinda like:

```
if (fileName.EndsWith(".craft", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    selection = MessageBox.Show(RadioButton("folder one"), RadioButton("folder two"));
    if (selection == "folder one")
    {
       ...do this...
    }
    else
    {
       ...do this...
    }
}
```

Comment: Common messagebox still have up to 3 custom buttons, if you could use button instead of radiobox it would be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is custom message box territory.

You'll have to build it yourself.

You'll need to create a new form, and implement a property to return the value of the selected radio button (if any)